# rails 3 - pre-processing and adding inputs fields before ajax form is submitted

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, forms

I have a AJAX form  in Rails 3. Given the nature of my app, I need to call `.submit()` on the form programatically. But before the AJAX request is sent to the server, I want to perform some client side logic on the form data. And in this logic, I add hidden input fields inside the form being submitted.

So I have two questions:

1. what is the recommended way to do this client side pre-processing upon the submission of an AJAX form which is Rails friendly?
2. will the hidden input fields I add during this pre-processing be successfully sent in the POST request, as intended?

Thanks.

UPDATE --
I answered question 1 by using the .submit() event handler. But it looks like the hidden input field I add to the form in that logic is not being sent in the POST request. Any ideas on how I can overcome this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its quite simple, you can use the jQuery .submit() event handler as well.

```
$('form_selector_here').submit(function()  {

   // pre process form here, add fields using $.append() etc
   $(this).ajaxSubmit();

   // or
   $.ajax({
    // settings here;   
   })

 })
```

For .ajaxSubmit() , you need to use the Jquery Form Plugin http://jquery.malsup.com/form/#getting-started